# dired+ not open in same buffer

Tags: dired

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 26.1, dired+-20170818.1411

I want (in `dired` mode) to open all folders in ONE buffer when press `Enter`.
So in my `init.el`

```
(diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

But it not help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Dired+, but I've bound this function to `RET` in `dired-mode-map` and it works for me in regular Dired:

```lisp
(defun mu-find-file-reuse-dir-buffer ()
  "Like `dired-find-file', but reuse Dired buffers."
  (interactive)
  (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
  (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
    (if (file-directory-p file)
        (find-alternate-file file)
      (find-file file))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "dired+", but for normal `dired` you can try:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'dired-find-alternate-file)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "^") (lambda () (interactive) (find-alternate-file "..")))
```

basically it will stop "buffer madness" when opening new directory....

more details you can find here:

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_tips.html

Comment: Not help. Same result.

Comment: what about `A` instead of `Enter` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Command `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir` toggles whether Dired `find-file` commands reuse directories. That has nothing to so with showing the contents of "all folders in ONE buffer".

In a Dired buffer you can use `i` on any subdirectory line to insert its contents in the current buffer. It sounds like that is closer to what you are looking for.

You can mark all subdirectories in the buffer, using **`* /`**. Then you can insert all of their contents into the buffer using **`M-i`**. I think that's what you're looking for.

(If you want to do this automatically and always, in your init file (which I don't recommend), you just write a function that invokes both of those commands, and then put that function on one of the Dired hooks.)

Comment: I want to use one buffer when in dired mode press Enter

Comment: I mean one buffer... when open "helm-mini" to show only last folder name. Not all folders that I open before.

Comment: I found the problem When I press Enter - it's ok. In "helm-mini" show ONLY LAST entered folder. But if I use "Jump to bookmark" than show MANY folders in "helm-mini" buffer. How I can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying/asking in these comments. Likewise, your question post. What do you mean by "open" all folders in one buffer? Are you talking about adding the listings of all subdirectories to the top-level directory listing? That's what "including" a subdir listing (e.g. `i`) does.

Comment: I mean this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44484/jump-to-bookmars-how-show-only-last-folder

Comment: If what you mean for this question is the same as that question then this one should be closed as a duplicate. Is that really the case? I've already voted to close emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44484/…because that one unclear (to me, at least). Hopefully someone else will understand what you're asking (here and there) and provide a useful answer (or two answers, if the questions are in fact different).